# Method name expected?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a asp button where i would like to link to a javascript method.

```
<ICCM:ICCMImageButton ID="btnClose" runat="server" meta:resourcekey="btnResClose" TabIndex="9" OnClick="CloseIFrame()"/>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function CloseIFrame() {
        alert("close");
    }
</script>
```

I have also tried this function in the j query document ready, but this had no effect.

In my C# i have added to my page load:

```
Page.Header.DataBind();
btnClose.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "CloseIFrame();");
```

When i try run my project i get the error method name expected. which points me to the line my button is on.

This all the info i get, am i missing something?

Comment: You may need `OnClientClick`

Comment: @DarrenDavies I replaced onclick with OnClientClick and removed the js function out the document.ready and this has worked. :) thanks so much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`OnClick` in asp.net controls is for server-side methods. Try `OnClientClick` instead.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
OnClientClick="CloseIFrame()"
```

Answer (score 1):

ICCMImageButton is a server control.  This would usually mean that the OnClick handler would be expected to be a server side handler.

The typical syntax for a client side handler would be OnClientClick.